# How to retrieve the database in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I have one doubt on hyperledger fabric where the ledger database will save please let me know. How to restore the ledger data when we lost the device.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use CouchDB, hosted on a different server and use it's configurations while setting up Peers for the network. Each Peer must have a configuration for it's own DB. If you don't provide this configuration, LevelDB would be used which is a built in file system DB for peers.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB or LevelDB is used as a *state store*, which stores the latest data only  and does not have the entire ledger data. So, although you could retrieve the latest data from them, I'm afraid you can't use them for recovery of the entire ledger, including history.

As far as I can see, the best way to restore the data would be to abandon the peer, create a new one and get synchronized from other peers.

To accomplish that, you must have two peers in advance; once a peer is down, create a new one and participate it to the network. That way, the new peer will receive the data from the sane peer.